# Modifying code of package downloaded via JuliaPro

Tags: package, julia, open-source, julia-jump, coin-or-cbc

I have an issue with my JuliaPro installation:

I want to add a function in the Cbc C interface, but all I have in my JuliaPro installation directories are include files and dynamic libraries.

Can I keep my JuliaPro installation as is and still have access to the Cbc source or do I need to go back to a standard installation ?

Many thanks,